# How to show snackbar on load of scaffold in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use an if else condition to show either a Widget or a Snackbar depending on a value from scoped model. I am getting error:`This Scaffold widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
I/flutter (15840): process of building widgets.` So I was trying to write a function which will get invoked when the loading of Scaffold is complete and the inside that it will check the condition and show the SnackBar. I was not able to find any solution.

Comment: pls paste your Code

Comment: Hi, have you managed to do that ?